# I Have Question on Google Indexing,

Tags: magento2, seo, indexing

I have a one website with 2 languages arabic and english but english which is ranked in google within a 2 days but arabic language dint rank since from 3 weeks why? Whats the reason? It is a e-commerce website developed by magento.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google will do whatever it likes with your content (unfortunately), however, you can help the process by:

> - Setting up a Magento sitemap for each website (under 'Marketing')
> - Registering with Google Webmasters (Search Console) and adding each site as a distinct property. Ensure you verify each and link the
>     sitemap you created.
> - If the websites have the same content, just translated, then ensure you have the correct hreflang tags on each page so Google understands
>     there is an English version and an Arabic version